# pod init state, while installing jenkins with helm in k8s

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

here is the the pvc yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: jenkins-pvc
  namespace: default
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 200Gi
  storageClassName: standard
```

here is the storage class:

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: standard
provisioner: kubernetes.io/aws-ebs
parameters:
  type: gp2
  fsType: ext4
reclaimPolicy: Retain
allowVolumeExpansion: true
mountOptions:
  - debug
volumeBindingMode: Immediate
```

--
here is the pv

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: jenkins-pv
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 200Gi
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
    - ReadOnlyMany
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  storageClassName: standard
  hostPath:
    path: /data/shared/jenkins
```

---

Here is the command am using:

```
helm install --set persistence.existingClaim=jenkins-pvc --set master.serviceType=NodePort stable/jenkins --generate-name 
error : Pod init state.
```

here is the init container error:
here is the init container error  [map[containerID:docker://1e2d565bfde2a84410a63d028b73215fd4c81fd552cc246e0c517e4c76c69c67 image:jenkins/jenkins:lts imageID:docker-pullable://jenkins/jenkins@sha256:d5069c543e80454279caacd13457d012fb32c5229b5037a163d8bf61ffa6b80b lastState:map[terminated:map[containerID:docker://1e2d565bfde2a84410a63d028b73215fd4c81fd552cc246e0c517e4c76c69c67 exitCode:1 finishedAt:2020-01-07T07:13:13Z reason:Error startedAt:2020-01-07T07:06:18Z]] name:copy-default-config ready:false restartCount:4 state:map[waiting:map[message:back-off 1m20s restarting failed container=copy-default-config pod=jenkins-1578379025-ccf77dfc-wtnww_default(ca6e0e22-7cf6-487d-b6e4-0223a1dc46a0) reason:CrashLoopBackOff]]]]

Can anyone help?

Comment: Hi, check the logs of the pod, `kubectl get pod` and `kubectl logs -f $POD_NAME`

Comment: Error from server (BadRequest): container "jenkins" in pod "jenkins-1578311090-5d469d474-t9hrt" is waiting to start: PodInitializing

Comment: check with `kubectl describe pod $POD_NAME`

Comment: Events:
  Type     Reason   Age                   From                     Message
  ----     ------   ----                  ----                     -------
  Warning  BackOff  2m45s (x69 over 94m)  kubelet, myserver  Back-off restarting failed container

Comment: could you add the `kubectl get pods $PODNAME -o yaml` in your question ?

Comment: Long output to paste here, other alternatives to share the yaml?

Comment: add it in the question, or crate a public gist and put the link here https://gist.github.com/

Comment: "https://gist.github.com/bratiacharya/6bdb3ada853eee8db0480c94fed08958.js"

Comment: here is the init container error :

Comment: initContainerStatuses:
  - containerID: docker://d3443a0b69dfa29e90fdc85e9469647b6d574e310ca2cd2f6a5dc382dea0b72b
    image: jenkins/jenkins:lts
    imageID: docker-pullable://jenkins/jenkins@sha256:d5069c543e80454279caacd13457d012fb32c5229b5037a163d8bf61ffa6b80b
    lastState:
      terminated:
        containerID: docker://a8885daecd90f656bd476146845b8be93df7bafebad53a7bb7c6f8ecc5664705
        exitCode: 1
        finishedAt: "2020-01-08T12:25:50Z"
        reason: Error
        startedAt: "2020-01-08T12:18:55Z"
    name: copy-default-config
    ready: false

Comment: as @SureshVishnoi suggested earlier, can you add `kubectl logs $POD_NAME` to your question if any? Another thing is that the container is exiting with exit code 1 which suggests its app issue for some reason (basically it means its not kubernetes killing the container)